# How do you configure the Transaction time out in Entity Framework 6 DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction?

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

Using code like

```
using (var tran = Ctxt.Database.BeginTransaction()) {
```

How can I set a value for the transaction timeout ?

Answer (score 6):

If for whatever reason you need to manage transactions yourself it is much easier to use [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149852.aspx). It has several constructors accepting a `TimeSpan` parameter to set the timeout. For instance

```
using(var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)))
{
    using(var ctx = new MyContext())
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
    ts.Complete(); // Try - catch to catch TimeoutException
}
```

I'm curious though why you want to set transaction timeout, not command timeout.

Comment: please tell me what is the default transaction timeout in entity framework?

Comment: When using TransactionScope with MS SQL Server, I get the following error:

_The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed_.

It does not happen with Oracle. If I use DbContext.BeginTransaction, it works with both databases.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to use `Database.CommandTimeout`:

```
var timeout = 60; //or whatever value you need
Ctxt.Database.CommandTimeout = timeout;
using (var tran = Ctxt.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    //do stuff
}
//this line can be skipped if you're about to dispose context
Ctxt.Database.CommandTimeout = null; //setting back default timeout
```

Of course, you can nicely wrap it in some class.

Comment: CommandTimeout  is for the duration of a single command
A transaction scope can have multiple commands
Therefore @GertArnold  answer is correct

Comment: @GertArnold's answer offers an alternative, but technically it doesn't answer the question.